# How much power does a mac mini uses?

Tags: mac-mini, power-management

I would like to know how much power would a mac Mini consume per month/year if:

- always powered,  but under very low load web server
- OS, probably Ubuntu
- two drives: one SSD and one HD.
- model Early 2010, Core duo 2

I know that the [manufacturer specification](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3468) says it would consume between 11W-85W.

How can I convert this to Amps?

Comment: That largely depends on how much power you need to draw for whatever you are running on it...

Answer (score 7):

If the idle power consumption was 11 W and the maximum was 85 W, the average might be something like 15 W if it's under very low load.

That would be about 500 MJ per year (15*86400*365).

If you paid 0.15 USD per kilowatt hour for electricity and the Mac mini was on all the time, it would cost about 20 USD per year (0.15*0.015*24*365).

15 W is about 65 mA with 230 V (European) voltage and 125 mA with 120 V (North American) voltage.

Comment: Thanks! BTW, how does this relates to the pricing asked for electricity by the hosting providers. I've seen that they specify things like: 2A and pay x$ for every additional 0.5A.